# How to make spreadsheet cell return its own value - 1?

Tags: excel, spreadsheet

I want to make cell M4 subtract 1 from itself if it has a value of more than 7.5. I am currently using the formula =SUM(L4-K4)*24.

Is this even possible? Ideally I would like to not add another column

Comment: That is the formula currently in M4?

Comment: =SUM(L4-K4)*24 is currently in M4. The formula =SUM(L4-K4)*24-1 does what I want but indescriminately. I only want that to happen when the first formula returns more than 7.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So something like this:

```
=IF(SUM(L4-K4)*24>7.5,SUM(L4-K4)*24-1,SUM(L4-K4)*24)
```

---

One note, as you have it you do not need the SUM():

```
=IF((L4-K4)*24>7.5,(L4-K4)*24-1,S(L4-K4)*24)
```

Comment: Think that's done it mate. Thanks so much. I was really struggling